# Can you shorten an 'if' statement where a certain variable could be multiple things

Tags: javascript, operators

Since I sometimes needs an if-statement like

```
if (variable == 'one' || variable == 'two' || variable == 'three') { 
    // code
}
```

I was wondering if you could write this any shorter, something like:

```
if (variable == ('one' || 'two' || 'three')) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: Been asked before... indexOf is your friend

Comment: Put them into an array

Comment: @JaromandaX It only seems to work when `variable == 'one'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or ..

```
if (~['one', 'two', 'three'].indexOf(variable))
```

any cat with many ways to skin it

`~` is **bitwise NOT** ... so -1 becomes 0, 0 becomes -1, 1 becomes -2 and so on

so ... ~ with indexOf is "truthy" when indexOf is 0 or greater, i.e. value is found ...

basically it's a shortcut that I probably wouldn't use in code expected to be read by other people as over half would scratch their heads and wonder what the code did :p

Comment: But it would be nice of you to explain the `~` coercion

Comment: should I explain `indexOf` while I'm at it? :p

Comment: Wow that is sneaky. I'll be sure to use it next time I want my coworkers to hate me.

Comment: btw it's "complement" otherwise it means 1 is saying nice things about you.

Comment: that's how I use it ... went on 10 days leave today, and scattered ~ in code everywhere :p

Comment: [The curious case of the coercion ~ (Bitwise NOT)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NOFwBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA75&ots=DtMt3b5JFv&dq=the-curious-case-of-the%20coercion&pg=PA78#v=onepage&q=the-curious-case-of-the%20coercion&f=false)

Comment: I guess the reason I used it in the answer ...  the question was to **shorten**, so I did :p

Comment: by the way, if you want coworkers to really hate you, coerce it to a Boolean ... `!!~`

Comment: Never tried that one, but I have some !!+ and +!! in my code because the back-end sends "1" and "0" for booleans ;)

Comment: that's a nice one! :)

Comment: @mplungjan that's a really nice book series I didn't knew. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
if(variable in {one:1, two:1, three:1})
```

or:

```
if(['one', 'two', 'three'].indexOf(variable) > -1)
```

or in ES6 (works natively in most recent browsers now):

```
if(new Set(['one', 'two', 'three']).has(variable))
```

Note that solution 2 will scale linearly with the size of the array, so it's not a good idea if you have more than a few values to check against.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no shortcut for such multiple comparisons. If you try it, it will calculate the value of the expression `('one' || 'two' || 'three')` and then compare that to the variable.

You can put the values in an array and look for it:

```
if ([ 'one', 'two', 'three' ].indexOf(variable) != -1) {
    // code
}
```

You can use a switch:

```
switch (variable) {
  case 'one':
  case 'two':
  case 'three':
    // code
}
```

You can look for the values among object properties (but the object values are just dummies to allow the properties to exist):

```
if (varible in { 'one': 1, 'two': 1, 'three': 1 }) {
    // code
}
```